# Nginx 504 Timeout Error within Docker container running Django and loading Scikit-learn model into memory

Tags: django, docker, nginx, scikit-learn, supervisord

I'm building a web app with Django that uses a pre-trained scikit-learn model to process data that an user inputs through a web form. During development I'm able to load the model into memory by running the following command in urls.py

```
modelRF = joblib.load('model.pkl')
```

However, when I try to deploy the app inside a Docker container I receive a 504 Gateway Timeout Error. I've tried increasing the timeout limits in the nginx.conf file without any success. I was wondering whether this could also be a problem with the amount of memory assigned to the container.

I'm not sure whether the problem is related to Docker or to the way I'm loading the model into memory while in deployment (rather than in development). I'm using docker-compose with nginx, supervisor and uwsgi.

My nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock; # for a file socket
}

server {
    listen      80 default_server;

    server_name .example.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/docker/code/media;
    }

    location /static {
       alias /home/docker/code/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include /home/docker/code/uwsgi_params; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get 504 for all requests or just for some "big" ones?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but with a flask app.  Did you manage to find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Add **uwsgi_read_timeout** directive inside django location curly braces like this:

```
location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include /home/docker/code/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 3000;
}
```